# Could Candide Thovex have avoided a crash by maximizing vertical air resistance?

Tags: kinematics, projectile, drag

**NOTE: This is a very "practical" question and involves quite a lot of estimation. I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to post this question. If it is, please comment where I could post it instead.**

[Candide Thovex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candide_Thovex) is considered by many to be the world's best freeskier. In 2007 he attempted to jump on one of the largest skiing jumps that had ever been built at that time, called "The Big Bertha". He came just a few meters short and landed "flat". Many thought at first that he was dead, but he managed to make it out alive with a broken back, knee and hands.

Here are the only videos I could find of the jump (the first one is much better quality):

- [Video 1](https://youtu.be/cpi2fc5vfNs?t=2152)
- [Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDjIPJBq97s)

As you can see he landed a few meters short (even 1-2 meters more would have been enough for him to land more properly). My question therefore is: **Could he have increased his vertical air resistance by so much that his horizontal speed would have taken him 1-2 meters further horizontally?**

**Here's some more analysis.** Let's first of all assume that there is no wind. I also don't know at what altitude the jump was, so let's assume that the density of the air is $\rho \approx 1.2 \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{m^3}}$.

To make things a bit easier, let's also assume that the point where Candide Thovex will start to increase his air resistance is at the maximum height of the trajectory (so when he's at the highest point). This is also rather logical, because (from own experience) you can not really decide before you start to go down whether your speed isn't enough to be able to make it over the flat part. Okay, how should he maximize his vertical air resistance? I think it's rather safe to say that the position he has to be in would be something similar to the position [ski jumpers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ski_jumping) are in (with the body covering as much area as possible). Let's also here assume that he would be able to change to this position without losing his balance in the air.

This is essentially the question. **If he changed to ski-jumping-position somewhere at the top of the trajectory, could the change in vertical air resistance have taken him 1-2 meters further horizontally?**

I tried to solve this question myself, but I'm a high-school student and not that good at physics. So first of all, we need some numbers. I timed the jump and the total time from the jump to impact was around $t_{total} \approx 2.55 \, \mathrm{s}$. The time from the top of the trajectory to impact was around $t_{top} \approx 1.9 \, \mathrm{s}$. I couldn't find a polite figure of how long the flat part was (which is slightly more than the horizontal distance travelled by Candide), but they say in Video 1 that it was "like 44 meters" and some figures online agree with this. Candide landed a little short so let's use something like $d_x = 43 \, \mathrm{m}$. This means that his horizontal speed was $v_x \approx 16.9 \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$. This means that in order for him to come over the flat part (which was 1-3 meters longer) he should have been $0.06-0.18 \mathrm{s}$ longer in the air (in order for $v_x$ to take him over the flat part).

Then to the air resistance. The force of air resistance can be modelled with [the equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation):

$$F_{air} = \frac{1}{2}\rho ACv^2 = \frac{1}{2}\rho kv^2$$

I couldn't continue from here, but my idea was to compare the constant $k = AC$ in both scenarios (the one where he lands flat and the one where he lands roughly 2-3 meters further away horizontally) and then check whether such a change in the constant $k$ would be possible only by changing your position in the air.

I know air resistance problems can become quite complex but if anyone could provide even a little insight it would be cool.

Comment: That was a cool (hot) jump, even if he got knocked out (from my point of view; I only jumped a few times during my stay in Kitzbuhel). It looks so easy... Of course one must have the guts too. But concerning your question. There is also a horizontal force of friction involved too. I think that this resistance has a bigger influence on the length of his jump. If Candide would force himself in a completely horizontal position at the top of the parabola, he would have a chance to bridge the 2-3 meter flat area. Of course, the vertical friction component would keep him in the air a bit longer.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Yeah I agree! It looks easier on camera than it really is. I really recommend you watch the full documentary (video 1), it's definitely one of the best skiing movies ever made!

Comment: I've looked at the documentary. Man! That guy does things I can only dream about (which can be very good for real practice!)...I'm very curious now if it's really possible that Candide could have completed his jump if he would have made himself flat at the top (is that allowed?). I saw that C=0,04 for a streamlined body, so... I'll elaborate!